# Ant path style regex with alternation

Tags: java, ant

Is there alternation for ant path style regex?

Seems to me that java [org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) can not handle "|" in the regex.

Is there a way to write ant path style regex which check if a path matches ANY of the patterns given?

For example, I wish to check if the given path matches any of the following patterns.

["/foo/me", "/bar/me", "/foobar/me"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant's `filename` selector works fine with `|` in the regex pattern.

```
<fileset id="testpath" dir="${parent.dir}">
    <filename regex="/foo/me|/bar/me|/foobar/me" />
</fileset>

<echo>${toString:testpath}</echo>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#filenameselect